# PHPMailer created email showing html tags in the body rather than only text?

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email with attachment, but I have a problem I am able to send an email but rather than having text it is having html tags present in it.

Here is the excerpt of the code.. 
http://pastebin.com/8nFkbMyP

So the I see the body of the message with html tags rather only with plain text, I am specifying the body to be html using function `isHtml(true)`

Snapshot of the result : [image: The Email Sent]

I just want the Text Shah, Dhruvenkumar

I have spent considerable amount of time, but could not find the solution. I also have double quotes within the HTML as the actual message is much more complicated.

I will be glad if someone could provide some pointers.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried sending to different email addresses and viewing the email in different email programs to see if you get this consistent result? Or does it just do this in Gmail?

Comment: I checked this using gmail email on thunderbird and on gmail web client, both have same result.

Comment: I don't see where you specify your Host or how you are sending the message. Should have something like this: $mail->Host = '123.123.123.123'; $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

Comment: No need i am using built in linux/unix functionality which can internally use mail function. Problem Solved.. use MsgHTML($message) wrap the message inside this function rather than $mail->body = $message;